# Display element inside table row outside the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table with the following structure:

```
<table>
  <thead>..</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
  <td>some</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>etc</td>
</tr>

<tr class="certain">
  <td><div class="that-one"></div>some</td>
  <td>content</td>
  <td>etc</td>
</tr>

several other rows...
<tbody>
</table>
```

And I am trying to figure out what to do with the `<div class="that-one">` (or any other element, if needed) inside the table so it can be painted outside the table.

I have tried the negative left property, `transform: translateX(-20px)`, and `overflow: visible`.

I know that there is something different with rendering HTML tables. I cannot change the structure of the table just can add whatever element inside.

Finding: both negative left property and `transform: translateX(-20px)` work in Firefox and Safari but don't work in Chrome (behaves like `overflow: hidden`).

Have some Javascript workaround on my mind, but would rather stay without it.

Also, I don't want it as CSS pseudoelement, because there will be some click event binded.

Comment: I think you are not following the code structure tag `<tr/>` can only be inside `<thead/>`, `<tbody/>` and `<tfoot/>` as your last is not inside `<tbody/>`  neither `<tfoot/>`

Comment: First of all that html is a bit wrong. Put the tr and td tags INSIDE the tbody.
Also. What exactly are you trying to do? Why put the element `inside` the table if you wish to render it `outside` the table?

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed My bad, this was just a typo.. In my code it is obviously inside <tbody>, I have updated it in question.

Comment: @arm It is supposed to be a "label" of the row.. I cannot change the whole structure, so this is why I am asking.

Comment: I am just bit confuse with paint out, if you want .that-one div to moving around anywhere like tip or  info, you can play with `position:relative` on table and `position:absolute;` you .that-one div.

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed Yes, this usually works but not within html table.. this is point of the question. In chrome, any part of .that-one outside the table is invisible.